# How to export an environment variable inside window manager?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I can

```
export VAR="value"
```

and use $VAR from within a terminal until I close it.

Is there a way to get this behaviour, inside a window manager/graphical environment? exporting an environment variable to be used by all applications inside it until closing it?

NOTE: I'm not asking how to persist environment variables through sessions, I know about .profile, .bash_rc, .bash_login and further methods. I just want to have an environment variable available in a graphical environment without having to restart it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicit support in your WM/DE (<strike>and I'm unaware of any that do</strike> As akira points out [in another answer](https://superuser.com/a/872046/414099) fluxbox supports doing this. If you use fluxbox, use that answer instead) you can do a couple of things.

### Launch your programs from a terminal

Instead of using the graphical launcher(s), you can instead start a terminal, export your environment in it's shell, then use that to launch other applications.

```
export VAR="whatever"
nameOfGUIProgramExpectingVAR &
differentProgram &
```

The terminal then becomes a sort of perpetual run box. This also has the advantage of being able to have a couple different launch points, each with different environments for their launched programs.

### Replace your GUI launcher via the method above

This might not work for all desktop environments. If running Ubuntu and Unity, for example, you can set environment variables and replace the running launcher. I expect similar could be done with gnome-panel or KDE, but YMMV.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my/custom/path
compiz --replace ccp &
disown %1
```

This adds a new entry to the path for the shell in the terminal and all programs it launches. Then it runs compiz (the window manager for unity) with "--replace" which causes the old one to exit and the new one to take its place. The `disown` line makes it un-associated with the terminal, so that the terminal can be closed without affecting the window manager. Now, programs launched by Unity will now all have the new PATH.

Note: that when doing this, your windows may get shuffled around, but they will remain running. All programs already running will still be using the old environment, but new ones will get the new environment.

Note: some programs try to be singletons (e.g. {Open,Libre}Office, firefox) and don't launch new instances of themselves when run if an existing instance already exists. Those programs will also continue to use the old environment until fully exited and then launched anew.

Note: If the controlling program of your X session ***is*** the window manager, this will likely cause X to exit (for example, if you started X with `xinit`which compiz` ccp. Typically there will be some kind of session manager that is the controlling entity. **You should experiment on an unimportant session prior to trying this on an important session!**

To be clear, you want only to replace the part of your DE that does the launching, not the whole DE.

Comment: @akira edited to link to your answer in the case of fluxbox

Answer (score 3):

[fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/) can do this natively: Add a **CommandDialog** entry to your menu or bind a key to it. A text box will open and you can enter commands. Among these is: `export FOO=BAR`:

[image: fluxbox' CommandDialog in action]

Read http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-keys.php and search for **CommandDialog**.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible as far as I'm aware.

Environment variables for an X session are read in the same way and from the same places as terminal environment variables,  so your only option is to edit your `~/.xsessionrc` file and restart X.

Usually logging out and back in has this effect, you don't necessarily need to restart your whole PC.

See [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82120/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-a-unity-session) for more detail.

Comment: my intention is not to even restart X, but if that's not possible as you say :-(